# "TreeMap does not take parameters" Compilation Error

Tags: java, compiler-errors, treemap

This is my code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class TreeMap {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String,Integer> treemap = new TreeMap<String,Integer>();
        Some code to fill the treemap ie treemap.put("Kevin", 36);
    }
}
```

And I am getting this compiler error:

```
TreeMap.java:5: error: type TreeMap does not take parameters
   Map<String,Integer> treemap = new TreeMap<String,Integer>();
                                            ^
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use full qualified class name for the Java TreeMap class

```
new java.util.TreeMap<String,Integer>()
```

Comment: I'm getting another compile error: TestMapTree.java:1: error: ';' exptected
It refers to my import line, and ofcourse the ; is already present

Comment: I misunderstood your comment at first. But this did solve my problem, thank you!
Why is this happening?

Comment: The following code works fine for me:

import java.util.*;


public class TreeMap {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String,Integer> treemap = new java.util.TreeMap<String,Integer>();

    }
}

Answer (score 9):

```
public class TreeMap
```

rename your class. It clashed with `java.util.TreeMap`

The compiler thinks that `new TreeMap<String,Integer>()` refers to your own class, which doesn't take any parameters.

Comment: Did not help, I renamed it to TreeMapTest and I'm getting the same errors.

Comment: it is the same code; except public class TestMapTree { } and import java.util.TreeMap<String,Integer>();

Comment: Did you rename the file to TestMapTree.java in which this class is defined, Also, looks like you changed the import statement, please leave the import statement as `import java.util.TreeMap;`

Comment: I did. What fixed my problem was:
Map<String,Integer> treemap = new java.util.TreeMap<String,Integer>();

Also, I realized I had to use static type SortedMap to be able to access firstKey and lastKey methods.

Comment: @user3302053 There's no need to use the full class name if you are importing the class.

Answer (score 2):

To clarify Eran's comment, import java.util.* imports everything in java.util, which includes java.util.TreeMap and a bunch of things you're not using. This is usually not good programming practice because it means that there are more names potentially in conflicts with names that you choose to use (like what happened to you above). Instead of importing java.util.* in the future, try importing only the objects that you actually need.